# Is is feasible to use the single self-signed certificate on multiple machines which are two way ssl communicating

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have came across a situation where I need to have same certificate on 4 machines which are communicating with each other in a two way ssl.

Will it be problematic to have same certificate on client as well as server side for two way ssl communication.?

Thanks,
Vinds

Comment: This question appears to have nothing to do with programming, but rather system administration.  Voting to migrate to Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

A server certificate usually lists its host name as the common name component of the subject, and it can also appear in the subject alternative names too. When establishing a connection, most applications expect the host name in the certificate to match a name of the host to which the connection is made; this is application level though, and not part of the SSL protocol itself.

Re-using the same certificate for many clients is not a problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot erickson for your answer.
I really apppreciate a quick response..!!

Currently we dont want to enable the hostname verification.

Now I would like to know, two servers communicating with each other in a "two way ssl" fashion, and having the "same private key", will that be problematic?

Comment: @Vinds: No problem at all. I often test 2-way SSL with a single certificate and haven't found any issues.

Comment: That's right, as long as hostname verification is disabled, it's not a problem.